# Adding values to array on click in Arduino

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I am creating a program to add selected values to add into an array,I am using a function to display the selected values the function is working good with others so there is nothing wrong in it  , but in this after selecting the values i am getting 0001 displayed in display is there something wrong with logic please let me know

```cpp
void display (int row, int col, int arr[], bool inv)
{
    String msg = " ";
    for (int i=0; i < aCount, i++)
    {
        char str[10];
        if (i < aCount)
            sprintf(str, "%d", arr[i]);
        else
            sprintf(str, "%d", curId);
        msg += str;
    }
    aCount++;
}
```

When I input `1` I obtain `0001` as output, though I would expect `1` instead; moreover, if other values are selected they too should appear in the array

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the indention.

Comment: Please provide some snippet that compiles. And please fix the indentation.

Comment: With such a syntax error I doubt that you get 0001 in the display: `for (int i=0;i<aCount +1,i++)`

Comment: Please be more specific and add some examples of input and actual and expected output.

Comment: @Lundin Actually im just trying to save the values that are selected and retrieve them and display

Comment: What type is `String`?

Comment: @everyone: this is a `c++` question, not `c`; `String` is actually a `c++ class` in the *Arduino* library, [here's the docs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringConstructors)

Comment: @DineshKarthie it is **difficult** to understand what is the need of mixing `String` with `char[]` and `sprintf()`, and what you are doing looks overly convoluted. `String` has embedded capabilities for *concatenating* `int` values in a string. At the same time, using `String` is just a waste of *dynamic memory*, so a solution completely based on `sprintf()` and `char[]` would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your variable `arr` contains `0`. Since you are directly assigning it to `String`, this `0` is treated as a character rather than its face value.

Add 1 extra condition to avoid leading zeros. Body of loop

```
char str[10];
if (i < aCount)
   if (arr[i]!=0)
      sprintf(str, "%d", arr[i]);
else
   sprintf(str, "%d", curId);
msg += str;
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I disagree with this: *"`0` is treated as a character rather than its face value"*. `arr[i]` is treated as an `int` because of the `%d` format modifier in `sprintf()`, and a `0` is printed because the *ASCII* representation of the number `0` is, unsurprisingly, `0`. If it was treated as a character, then it would become `\0`, which is commonly used as *string terminator*.